# Nginx does not process 2 paralell file requests

Tags: php, nginx, wamp

I am executing 2 different PHP files in my project. The first one has a while loop and is dependent on the second one to end this while loop

```
File 1
Execute while loop
Listen for updates by checking DB
Until no update continue in while or sleep 
If update exit

File 2 
Update the DB 
Exit
```

What's happening here is that when i start first file the second file does not process POST request until the first one is completed and hence both ends up in timeout. I tried it in WAMP and it works perfectly fine there but as Nginx is a single web worker it not working there. Can you Please tell me why this simple thing does not work in Nginx

Comment: nginx can't execute php, and therefore can't be related to your problem

Comment: Its configured with PHP-FPM FAST-CGI and therefore its executing the PHP code

Comment: NGINX is not Apache. They are different. Also PSEUDO Code is really no help at all in disgnosing this problem

Comment: PHP-FPM is a separate application/daemon, doesn't related to nginx, while FastCGI is just a protocol to pass the data between different applications (like http). So, nginx just connects to PHP-FPM and passes the request, and then it's up to PHP-FPM to execute PHP code.

Comment: So you mean the Nginx is passing both requests to PHP-FPM? and PHP FPM is not executing the second one because its busy in executing the first one? What will be the possible solution in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Check the php-fpm configuration. You need to configure more than one php-fpm worker processes.

Comment: Thanks i am not sure how to do it. Can you please give me some configuration to add in Nginx? I am confused do i have to add another instance of PHP in order to run another FPM?

Comment: As I've already said before, nginx has nothing to do with php-fpm, which is a different program with its own configuration file. You can learn about it on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php and http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

Comment: Well i just looked into the configuration and idi not find any worker option in **www.conf** as well as **php-fpm.conf**. Please tell me what needs to be updated for it to work. There is no worker configuration here and i don't wanna run another PHP7 as it should not be the solution there must be some config option for it to work. Cn you tell me what that option is?